# Is there a way to stream audio from MIC and play that stream in Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight, audio, stream, naudio

So I want to stream the audio from a mic using NAudio and then pass that stream to WCF  which a Siverlight app can consume to broadcast the live audio sound. I want the latency to be as low as possible.

Any suggestions or if some one has already done it please point the source. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

what you are asking is certainly possible, but will be a fair amount of work to do.
NAudio can handle to capturing microphone audio.

At the Silverlight end you can play custom audio formats (in this case PCM) using a custom media element streaming source. See this one: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wavmss

I suspect latency would not be very good. You can reduce it by keeping the buffer sizes small. Also bear in mind that WAV is not a very efficient format to be sending over the network.

Comment: Hi Heath, I have one question for you. I am also developing application using SL and it need to transmit the audio data to WCF server in real time. In that case I have to send every packet as a byte array to the server. It makes big over head, because everytime, it passes the SOAP message. How did you achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

To have low latency as possible, you should use the **netTcpBinding** and stream your audio in binary format. I would use MemoryStream for this and try to play with the buffersize to figure out what the best performance is. Also, try checking audio formats for best performance. This also depends of the audio quality you expect.